# Mysql Auditing for Security

Tags: mysql

Is there a Auditing tool for mysql?
When i googled i can see some triggeres and procedure which can say who is logged and how times and those informations are provided.
For DML we are able to store the before image of the table and that to it is for specific table.
I m looking for a auditing tool which can audit the security of the databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can't audit throug a tool...(you can but isn't right) 
A tool for security auditing is IBM Consul InSight but.. the price si too big. You can read some standards or some books and you can audit your security based on standards.. A tool isn't capable to analyse a problem from all points of view. A human person can, especially +two

For security auditing docs, you can visit [isaca](http://www.isaca.org/Knowledge-Center/Research/ResearchDeliverables/Pages/MySQL-Server-Audit-Assurance-Program.aspx) and for begin, you can read [oreily presentation](http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/2/Securing%20MySQL%20for%20a%20Security%20Audit%20Presentation.pdf) and after that... [isaca article](http://www.isaca.org/Journal/Past-Issues/2008/Volume-5/Pages/Database-Security-Compliance-and-Audit1.aspx)

I hope that my post can help you, and if you have more questions..go ahead.